# Unset child object static variable from abstract parent class php

Tags: php, laravel, abstract-class, static-variables, late-static-binding

I am using Laravel and it's Validators.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
class ResellerController extends BaseController{

    public function add() {

        //some code before

        $userValidator =  new App\Services\Validators\UserCreateValidator();
        //HERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE company KEY FROM THE RULES IN THE USERS CREATE VALIDATOR
        $userValidator->removeRule('company');      

        //code execution continues      
    }
}
```

The UserCreateValidator extends a parent Validator class:

```
namespace App\Services\Validators;

class UserCreateValidator extends Validator {

    public static $rules = array(
        'firstName' => 'required',
        'lastName' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'company' => 'required'
    );  
}
```

And here is the base Validator class:

```
namespace App\Services\Validators;

abstract class Validator {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules;

    //THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK IN THE CONTROLLER UP
    public static function removeRule($ruleKey){

        if(is_array($ruleKey))
        {
            foreach($ruleKey as $key)
            {
                if(!array_key_exists($key, static::$rules)) continue;

                unset(static::$rules[$key]);
            }

            return true;
        }

        if(!array_key_exists($ruleKey, static::$rules)) //return false;

        unset(static::$rules['company']);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The unsettting of the `static::$rules[$key]` in `ResellerController` does not work.

I can see in a **XDEBUG** session (after this line gets executed) that the `static::$rules['company']` is still present in the `UserCreateValidator` as property.

I thought that **Late Static Binding** should solve this problem?
What is wrong?

Comment: Just for testing... Does it work if you put the `removeRule` function in `UserCreateValidator`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It was in the commented part in the:

```
if(!array_key_exists($ruleKey, static::$rules)) //return false;
```

The unsetting is working fine after I uncomment the `return false`.

Silly mistake :)